# Malware/Permission bug removal?

Tags: security, permissions, wp-config

I'm facing a hell of a problem on a client's WP theme. Whenever I try to 'Activate' it, it gives me the following errors on a blank page:

> Warning: include(/homepages/32/d207857955/htdocs/wp-content/themes/kvinterior/functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /homepages/32/d207857955/htdocs/wp-settings.php on line 316
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/homepages/32/d207857955/htdocs/wp-content/themes/kvinterior/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php6') in /homepages/32/d207857955/htdocs/wp-settings.php on line 316
>
> Warning: include(/homepages/32/d207857955/htdocs/wp-content/themes/kvinterior/home.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /homepages/32/d207857955/htdocs/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 74
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/homepages/32/d207857955/htdocs/wp-content/themes/kvinterior/home.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php6') in /homepages/32/d207857955/htdocs/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 74

I think, the wp-config is changing the file permissions automatically which causes the problem. The hosting provider tells me that these four files are malware infected. If either or even if neither of the two cases prevail, please provide me a solution.

P.S. - All the other themes work perfectly fine.

Comment: why did you bother to attach an image if it is not readable? please remove it, improve it, or just copy the file name into the question.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize it until now, I've simply added the errors here now. Thanks for the heads up Mark

Comment: have you checked if the files actually exist at those locations, and do they have a read permission?

Comment: I change the permissions of all the files to 'read & write' before uploading, still the above problem persists.

Comment: are the files (funcrtion.php etc) in that specific location?

Comment: Yes, they too are in their appropriate location.

Comment: In that case why do you get the warning at all? I think you should first understand what is the cause for the warning, maybe with the help of your hosting support. If it is somehow blocked because "it contains malware" then they should exlain to you what is the malware and where is it located at those files.